# How to confine particles within a volume?

Tags: particles

Hi I am using Particle Properties - Hair to put slender particles inside a specific volume mesh (Emit from: Volume). But I find for some particles, they can go outside my volume. How can I confine particles within a volume? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Duplicate your main volume in place
2. Remove the particle system from the main volume
3. Scale down the duplicate so that the particles fit into the main volume
4. make sure to turn `Show Emitter` off in the `Particle Settings` panel

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answering! Is there a feature that goes with the original volume to confine the particles?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think the particle system is using the Origin of the particle object to determine its position within the volume.

Comment: OK! But this works pretty well though! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a solidify modifier on the emitter
2. Place it above the particle system in the modifiers stack
   [image]
3. Switch on 'Use Modifier Stack' under the particle system's Source options, if not already
4. Turn up the solidify thickness value until the particles are filled in properly